# How to center an image and then adjust it from the center?

Tags: html, css

I know this is a common question but what I need help with is after centering an image, I have to adjust it to the left by 250px. The idea is the original position should be at the center so i can adjust it from there.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried OR create fiddle of the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get it to the centre you can add

`margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;`.

To adjust it to the left you can add `padding-right:250px;`